# How can I correct the problem in a simple question

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I learnt on ros_ignite. I just start learning on topics.

The slogan is:
Create a package with a launch file that launches the code **simple_topic_publisher.py**.
Modify the code you used previously to publish data to the /cmd_vel topic.
Launch the program and check that the robot moves.
1.- The /cmd_vel topic is the topic used to move the robot. Do a rostopic info /cmd_vel in order to get information about this topic, and identify the message it uses. You have to modify the code to use that message.

2.- In order to fill the Twist message, you need to create an instance of the message. In Python, this is done like this: var = Twist()

3.- In order to know the structure of the Twist messages, you need to use the rosmsg show command, with the type of the message used by the topic /cmd_vel.

4.- In this case, the robot uses a differential drive plugin to move. That is, the robot can only move linearly in the x axis, or rotationaly in the angular z axis. This means that the only values that you need to fill in the Twist message are the linear x and the angular z.

5.- The magnitudes of the Twist message are in m/s, so it is recommended to use values between 0 and 1. For example, 0'5 m/s.

Here is the given code, but there is a problem:

move_robot.py

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

rospy.init_node('move_robot_node')
pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
rate = rospy.Rate(2)
move = Twist()
move.linear.x = 0.5 #Move the robot with a linear velocity in the x axis
move.angular.z = 0.5 #Move the with an angular velocity in the z axis

while not rospy.is_shutdown(): 
  pub.publish(move)
  rate.sleep()
```

move_robot.launch

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="exercise_21" type="move_robot.py" name="move_robot_node" output="screen" />
    
    </node>
</launch>
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>exercise_21</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The exercise_21 package</description>
  <maintainer email="user@todo.todo">user</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

Problem is:

```
user:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch exercise_21 move_robot.launch
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/d040bc5e-6476-11e8-88f0-065a2c6c1cb0/roslaunch-ip-172-31-47-59-17102.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 4, column 6
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

How can I correct the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292754/how-can-i-correct-the-problem-in-a-simple-question/) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-05-30**:
You should make short question that the answer is for eliminating single problem at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error indicates that there is a syntax error in your launch file: `Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 4, column 6`

"mismatched tag" in XML means that you have a close tag (starts with `</`) that the XML parser wasn't expecting. In this case, you've closed the `node` tag twice: once by using a self-closing tag (`<node/>`) and again with an explicit close tag on line 4, where the parser pointed out your error (`</node>`).

You should change your launch file so that you either use matching open and close tags ( `<node>` and `</node>` ) or use the self-closing tag ( `<node/>` )

I suggest

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="exercise_21" type="move_robot.py" name="move_robot_node" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-05-31**:
Thank you! You are right. But when I changed the .launch file. A new problem occurred...
It is said: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [exercise_21/move_robot.py]: can't locate node [move_robot.py] in package [exercise_21]
I tried to solve it by chmod +x move_robot.py

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-05-31**:
But a new problem occurred again, it is : Unable to launch [move_robot_node-1].
If it is a script, you may be missing a '#!' declaration at the top.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file.   Could you please tell me how to solve this one?

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-05-31**:
I solved problems in move_robot.py. I omitted the **#! /usr/bin/env python** in python file. I used to think it is useless.